# PHP Syntax Error with Postgresql INSERT query

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have been working with code for hours and just cannot see where I have an error. This is the offending code

```
$answercreatequery = pg_query("INSERT INTO answer (answerid, questionid, adescription, afilelocation, iscorrect) VALUES( default, '".$thisquestionid."', '".$adescription1."', '".$afilelocation."', '".$iscorrect1."' ");
```

And this is the error reported

> Warning: pg_query() [function.pg-query]: Query failed: ERROR: syntax
>   error at end of input LINE 1: ...on, iscorrect) VALUES( default, '37',
>   'kyfhdkj', 'none', '' ^ in
>   /ceri/homes1/m/mtp4/public_html/mmp/Quizmaker/Clientside/questioncreatescript.php
>   on line 167

I am wondering if there is something simple I am missing? I have suspected it was because $iscorrect1 is type boolean and I have tried editing it in many ways but still I get the same kind of error.

/d answer table

```
Column     |          Type          |                         Modifiers                         
---------------+------------------------+-----------------------------------------------------------

 answerid      | integer                | not null default nextval('answer_answerid_seq'::regclass)
 questionid    | integer                | not null
 adescription  | character varying(200) | not null
 afilelocation | character varying(200) | not null
 iscorrect     | boolean                | not null
Indexes:
    "answer_pkey" PRIMARY KEY, btree (answerid)
Foreign-key constraints:
    "answer_questionid_fkey" FOREIGN KEY (questionid) REFERENCES question(questionid)
```

Comment: I would first try hard-coding each of `$adescription1`, `$afilelocation`, etc. until you discover which of the four is the offender. It looks like it's probably `$iscorrect1`, so maybe try hard-coding that and see if the problem goes away.

Comment: Also, pasting a `\d answer` in your question might be helpful.

Comment: It was defined as serial. I've been using it for my other INSERT queries and it hasn't caused a problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You forgot a `)` at the end of your query:

```
$answercreatequery = pg_query("INSERT INTO answer (answerid, questionid, adescription, afilelocation, iscorrect) VALUES( default, '".$thisquestionid."', '".$adescription1."', '".$afilelocation."', '".$iscorrect1."' ");
........................................................................................................................................................................................................insert ) here ^
```

Besides that, you can simply omit the column where you want the default value to be used:

```
$answercreatequery = pg_query("INSERT INTO answer
  (questionid, adescription, afilelocation, iscorrect) VALUES
  ('".$thisquestionid."', '".$adescription1."', '".$afilelocation."', '".$iscorrect1."')");
```

Additionally, you should *really* use [`pg_query_params`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) (instead of escaping or having a sql injection hole):

```
$answercreatequery = pg_query_params('INSERT INTO answer
  (questionid, adescription, afilelocation, iscorrect) VALUES ($1, $2, $3, $4)',
  array($thisquestionid, $adescription1, $afilelocation, $iscorrect1));
```

Doing so also makes your code much more readable.

Comment: Thank you very much! I feel bad for making such a simple error! Also thank you for making me aware of pg_query_params, I'm going to spend some time looking into it further in the PHP manual.